Debug AWS Lambda Function With Layers
I am trying to debug locally my Lambda Function with VsCode, but it depends on a AWS Layer.
I have the following configuration:
        {
            "name": "Invoke Lambda",
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "code",
                "lambdaHandler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
                "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            },
            "aws": {
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "credentials": "profile:dev"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "python3.7",                
                "environmentVariables": {
                    "BUCKET_NAME": "mybucket",
                },
                "payload": {
                    "json": {
                        "time": "2024-05-14T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

How can I run with layers?
I have tried run with the template.yaml too, but without success...

Can you tell us more on what is your definition of run? Run in the cloud? Run in the local environment? can you share any error logs thrown by your code?

I need to run locally. I have an AWS Layer with Pandas and I wanna run with it
